# NullReferenceException using where clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a scenario that I am getting the result properly .But i have to search it in that result.Here is my code.

```
if(productSearch.Keyword !=null || productSearch.Code!=null)
{
    var key = productSearch.Keyword;
    var cod = productSearch.Code;

    if (productSearch.Code != null)
    {
        var Selected_Result = result.Results.Where(s => s.Code.ToLower().Contains(cod.ToLower())).ToList();                     
        result.Results = Selected_Result;
    }
    else
    {
        var Selected_Result = result.Results.Where(s => s.Keyword.ToLower().Contains(key.ToLower())).ToList();                        
        result.Results = Selected_Result;
    }
}
```

But it gives following exception :

> `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on  `result.Results.Where(s => s.Code.ToLower().Contains(cod.ToLower())).ToList();`

I know `s => s.Code.ToLower()` is coming `NULL`, but i dont know why, `result` has records.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `s.Code` is `null` in that case.

Comment: Looks like one of items in results has `Code` equal to `null`

Comment: Yes S.code is null, But how to get it.

Comment: productSearch.Code cannot be null.... but are you checking if result is null, more to the point result.code can be null eh.

Comment: Thx for time. Actually i was searching in wrong column.

Comment: did you ever figure this one out? I'm currently facing the same problem and I've already made sure that there are no null values involved.

Answer (score 4):

If it's `null` in the query then chances are it's `null` in the DB. To be on the safe side you can use the [null coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator to make sure you have at least *something* to call `ToLower` on e.g.

```
result.Results.Where(s => (s.Code ?? "").ToLower().Contains(cod.ToLower()))
              .ToList();
```

Comment: It's a `string`, it most certainly can be. If you mean it's a non-nullable at the DB side then, yeah, something's probably wrong with your mapping.

Comment: James wouldn't you rather use 'String.Empty'?

Comment: oh thx..I got my mistake.I actually searching in wrong column.

Comment: @Campl3r pretty sure EF doesn't support `String.Empty`. Regardless you aren't gaining much by using `String.Empty` over `""` anyway.

Comment: @James EF does accept `String.Empty` No gain indeed, just a coding choice... I also prefer `String.Empty`, but have no religion

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus you could argue that `String.Empty` is more readable, but you could also argue that if you don't know that `""` represents an empty string your probably in the wrong profession :)